# Is it possible to return a view (using blade) with two variables in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have to do one of these pages with a form that will search for a meal and its recipe according to a dishtype or cuisine type etc...
Here is my function to return the view but there is an error in the line that i show in bold below :

```
public static function SearchPage()
{
    $DishType = DishType::getAllDishType();
    $CuisineType = CuisineType::getAllCuisineType()

    return view("vueRecipeSearch", [
        'DishType' => DishType::getAllDishType(),
        CuisineType::getAllCuisineType()
    ]);
}
```

And Here is a part of a view where i would like to use a variable:

```
<label for="DishType">Dish type :</label>
  <select id="DishType" name ="DishType">
      @foreach($DishType as $Dish)
        <option value="Dessert">{{$Dish->dish}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
```

and i'd like to do the same with the cuisine type but can't because I don't know how to return multiple variables..

Comment: that is supposed to be an associative array passed to `view` ... the keys are the name of the variables in the view ... you didn't assign a key for the second value  "When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return view("vueRecipeSearch", [
        'DishType' => DishType::getAllDishType(),
        'CuisineType' => CuisineType::getAllCuisineType()
    ]);
```

Then you have access in your blade file with the array keys: `DishType` and `CuisineType`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously possible to send two variables from controller to blade.

```
$dishType'   = DishType::getAllDishType();
$cuisineType = CuisineType::getAllCuisineType();

return \view("vueRecipeSearch", compact('dishType', 'cuisineType'));
```

And on the blade file, you have to access these two variables like by `$dishType` and `$cuisineType`.

Answer (score 0):

return view ('vueRecipeSearch',compact('dishType', 'cuisineType'));
No Need Add Forward Slash or Backward Slash. Simple